# Check the existence of an object instance

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I'm surprised I don't know how to do this, but as it turns out I really don't; simply put, I'm trying to make a side-scrolling shooter game, a basic one and in it, I have 50 stars spawned on-screen through a "for" loop upon the game starting. There is a function which does this and a listener is at the beginning. Problem is, when you lose the game and go back to main menu, 50 more stars would be spawned, which isn't what I want. So, I'm trying to make an "if" statement check at the beginning, so that the game checks whether there is an instance/movie clip of the star object/symbol before determining whether the function that spawns stars should be called out with a listener. So, how do I do this? I looked through some other checks and they didn't help as the codes presented were vastly different there and so I'm just getting errors.

Let me know if a better explanation is needed or if you would like to see some of the code. Note that the game overall already has a lot of code, so just giving all of it would probably not be helpful.

Comment: Correct. Giving all of it would not be helpful. We suggest you make an example that is as simple as possible that causes the same problem. Often doing this you will discover the solution yourself, but if not, it gives us a great way to see your problem in action on our own computers.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you rethink your approach. You're focusing on whether stars have been instantiated. That's ok but not the most basic way to think about it.

I would do this instead

```
private function setup():void{
    loadLevel(1);
    addListeners();
    loadMusic();
    // etc...
    // call all functions that are needed to just get the app up and running
}

private function loadLevel(lev:int):void{
    addStars();
    // call all functions that are needed each time a new level is loaded
}

private function restartLevel():void{
    // logic for restarting level,
    // but this *won't* include adding star
    // because they are already added
}
```

There are other ways to do this but this makes more sense to me than your approach. I always break my game functions into smaller bits of logic so they can be reused more easily. Your main workhorse functions should (IMHO) primarily (if not exclusively) just call other functions. Then those functions do the work. By doing it this way, you can make a function like `resetLevel` by assembling all the smaller functions that apply, while excluding the part about adding stars.

Comment: Well, I have written a lot of code already and the method I thought of is a way that I'm pretty sure would work. I'm not about to re-write weeks long code just to get this one aesthetic thing working when I have only about a week to finish this little game and hand it in as an assignment. So please, could I have some assistance in what code I need to check whether even one of those stars within star container (the container's called starContainer btw) exist at the very beginning of the program so that I can make it so it then determines whether to spawn in stars or not.

Comment: Even though I still don't know how to do the check I've asked for here, I've figured out a way to get what I need; simply making the stars spawn once by setting the listener outside of the game starting function. But still, a code for this would be great for future purposes, so if anyone could provide some, that would be great.

Comment: That's precisely what I was saying to do. More or less

Comment: But you could also post what worked and mark it as the correct answer too. Good job getting it sorted.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I did to solve my problem... Here's what I had before:

```
 function startGame():void
 {
  starsSpawn();
  //other code here
 }
```

This is what I changed it to:

```
 starsSpawn();

 function startGame():void
 {
  //other code here
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

when you said **existance**, so there is a container, i named this container, (which contain stars , and stars was added to it) as starsRoot, which absolutely is a `DisplayObject` (right?)

now, to checking whole childrens of a `DisplayObject`, we have to do this :

```
for (var i:int=0; i<starsRoot.numChildren; i++) {
    var child = starsRoot.getChildAt[i];
}
```

then, how to check if that child is really star!?
**as you said**

> whether there is an instance/movie clip of the star

so your stars's type is MovieClip, and they don't have any identifier (name), so how to find them and make them clear from other existing movieclips. my suggestion :

define a **Linkage** name for stars from library, thats a Class name and should be started with a capital letter, for example **`Stars`**

[image]

now, back to the code, this time we can check if child is an instance of **`Stars`**

```
for (var i:int=0; i<starsRoot.numChildren; i++) {
    var child = starsRoot.getChildAt[i];
    if (child is Stars) {
        // test passed, star exist
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, not what I'm looking for. From my understanding, you're focusing on checking whether a star is a child of this particular container... I'm trying to make it so that the game checks whether any star within that container even exists.